# Why is List<int> not IEnumerable<ValueType>?

Tags: c#, .net

[Edit: My apologies ... the original question wording was ambiguous and I was not getting the responses I am looking for]

For any class X that inherits from class Y, `new List<X>() is IEnumerable<Y>` is true. However, this doesn't hold for structs: `new List<int>() is IEnumerable<ValueType>` is false. My question is: Why?

Here is a sample program:

```
class Program
{
    class Y { }
    class X : Y { }
    struct Z { }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test(new List<X>());
        Test(new List<string>());
        Test(new List<Z>());
        Test(new List<int>());
        Test("blah");
        Test(1);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void Test(object o)
    {
        if (o is IEnumerable<Y>)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(o + " is a list of Ys");
        }
        else if (o is IEnumerable<ValueType>)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(o + " is a list of ValueTypes");
        }
        else if (o is IEnumerable<object>)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(o + " is a list of objects");
        }
        else if (o is System.Collections.IEnumerable)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(o + " is most likely a list of ValueTypes or a string");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(o + " is not a list");
        }

    }
}
```

Output:

> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ConsoleApplication1.Program+X] is a list of Ys
>
> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] is a list of objects
>
> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ConsoleApplication1.Program+Z] is most likely a list of ValueTypes or a string
>
> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32] is most likely a list of ValueTypes or a string
>
> blah is most likely a list of ValueTypes or a string
>
> 1 is not a list

So why is `new List<int>` not a `IEnumerable<ValueType>`?

Comment: They result in false tests because they are false.

Comment: @BenRobinson: Why are they false? It is not false for string array. String is an object, Int32 is a ValueType which is also an object. Yes, Int32 is a struct, but the base is still a ValueType

Comment: Yes but you are not checking if int is a `ValueType` you are checking if lArr is an `IEnumerable<ValueType>` or a `List<ValueType>` and it is not it is a `List<int>`.

Comment: @BenRobinson: I think you are missing my point. if x inherits from y, `new List<x>() is y` should be true. It is true for string and any other object. It is false for int and any other struct/ValueType.

Comment: No i think you are missing my point if x inherits from y then it is not true that `ListList<x> is List<y>()` for any type

Comment: @BenRobinson: I'm sorry. I wrote the example wrong. I meant to write: `new List<X>() is IEnumerable<Y>` is always true. It is only not true if X is a struct and therefore Y a ValueType. Anyway, I'll rewrite my question as I am not getting the answers I expected

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Covariance works only for reference types, not for value types. So a `List<string>` is assignable to an `IEnumerable<object>` because `string` is a reference type, but a `List<int>` is not assignable to an `IEnumerable<ValueType>`. See section 13.1.3.2 of the C# language specifications for details

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for. "Variance applies only to reference types; if you specify a value type for a variant type parameter, that type parameter is invariant for the resulting constructed type." from [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics][1]

  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The type of `iArr` (and subsequently `iArr[i]`) is *known*; the compiler can tell you that your expressions will always return a given value because *it knows the answer at compile time*.  There is nothing dynamic going on here.

What are you actually trying to accomplish here?  Why would you test if an `int` derives from `ValueType`?  Of course it does; it's an `int`!  This would possibly make sense were generics involved (though you would likely just use a constraint), but not here.

Comment: Well ... this is just an example. The actual use case would be a function that accepts an object parameter and the test happens on the object with same result. Yes, the warnings are pretty obvious, but how come there is no warning for the string array comparison? Int32 is a ValueType ... the comparison should be treated similar to the string array comparison

Comment: @Rado: When asking a question a relevant example is pretty much required.  You still haven't told us *what you are actually trying to accomplish*, you have only asked how to solve the remaining 10% of your solution, and it's the part that doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

In your comments it looks like you expect `List<x>` deriving from `List<y>` if  x derived from y and hence you expect true for some of the checks. This is invalid assumption for `List<T>`.

If type `x` relates to type `y` you **can't** say anything about relation between `RandomGeneric<x>` and `RandomGeneric<y>` without looking at the types themselvs.

In your particular case `List<x>` and `List<y>` are always sibling types (derive from common parent, but have no relation between each other). The same goes for `IEnumerable<x>` and `IEnumerable<y>`.

Answer (score 0):

The question does not make sense iArr has value type in it because it is an array of ints.  The only time you are going to not know what the type an element is at compile time is if you have a collection of object.  Under that circumstance every element could be a different type cast as an object so you would have to check every element.

e.g.

```
IEnumerable arse = SomeMethodThatReturnsIEnumerable();    
bool areAllValueTypes = arse.<OfTypeobject>().All(x => x is ValueType);
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean.

```
var lst = new List<Object>();
lst.Add(1);
lst.Add(3);
```

This is a collection of objects which happens to only contain ValueTypes.
Should this return true or false?
If it should return false, use this:

```
private bool attemptOne(IEnumerable coll)
{
    var s = coll.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
    return s.IsValueType;
}

var lstTwo = new List<int>();
lstTwo.Add(1);
lstTwo.Add(3);
Console.WriteLine(attemptOne(lstTwo)); // Returns true
```

If it should return true, use this:

```
private bool attemptTwo<T>(IEnumerable<T> coll)
{
    return coll.All(c => c.GetType().IsValueType);
}
```

Note that the second way will take a long time for very large collections.

Comment: Your attemptTwo method is kind of pointless you would know at compile time whether it would return true in all circumstances apart from if T is an object.  It would be better to have a none generic method that takes a non generic ienumerable parameter.

Comment: @BenRobinson Yes, the whole point of it was if T was an object, which I even pointed out

Answer (score 0):

I think I can see what you are getting at

```
bool IsCollectionOfValueTypes(Object argValue)
{
  Type t = argValue.GetType();
  if(t.IsArray)
  {
    return t.GetElementType().IsValueType;
  }
  else
  {
    if (t.IsGeneric)
    {
      Types[] gt = t.GetGenericArguments();
       return (gt.Length == 1) && gt[0].IsValueType;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

A start anyway might get a bit more complicated if you pass in a multidimensional array or a contructed type. It's all in the class somewhere though.