# Lists, Reflection, IEnumerable, and a configuration issue

Tags: c#, collections, reflection

I am attempting to use reflection to detect collections such as `List<T>`.  Ultimately I need to operate without an instance available (i.e. via typeof only), and would like to detect collections beyond just `List<T>`, but to keep it simple here is a basic test case which fails:

```
Type type = (new List<string>()).GetType();
if (type.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(System.Collections.IEnumerable)))
{
    Console.WriteLine("True.");
}
else Console.WriteLine("False.");
```

I have also tried `IList` and `ICollection` to no avail.

While troubleshooting I encountered the following discussion:
[Why is List<int> not IEnumerable<ValueType>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8144473/why-is-listint-not-ienumerablevaluetype)

The OP of that discussion found his answer, that value types will not be detected by something like the above because covariance doesn't work for them.  However I am using string, a reference type and still not seeing covariance.  What's more curious (to me anyway), is that when I run the example code in the above discussion, I see a very different result:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[AssignableListTest.Program+X] is most likely a list of ValueTypes or a string
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] is most likely a list of ValueTypes or a string
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[AssignableListTest.Program+Z] is most likely a list of ValueTypes or a string
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32] is most likely a list of ValueTypes or a string
blah is most likely a list of ValueTypes or a string
1 is not a list
```

Leading me to believe I must have a configuration difference from that poster.  I am using Visual Studio 2005 and in this case .NET 3.5, although I need compatibility back to 2.0 if possible.  Actually, if I could get the result that poster had, it would be sufficient (identifying that `IEnumerable` is implemented), but when I use `Type.IsAssignableFrom()` in lieu of "is", they all give "is not a list".

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to flip the check:

```
type.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(System.Collections.IEnumerable))
```

becomes

```
typeof(System.Collections.IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(type)
```

Everybody makes that mistake at least once. It is a misleading API.

Comment: In my personal `ReflectionUtilities` I actually created two method wrappers around only `IsAssignableFrom` where the method/parameter names make it pretty clear which is which just because of this.