# Check if the object passed is IEnumerable<T> or a single value - Including T being a value types

Tags: c#, generics, ienumerable

In a part of my C# code, I have used the following code to check if an object passed in is a single value or implements `IEnumerable<T>` (`T` being string, double, int, etc - Never a complex object or class) :

```
Type type = paramValue.GetType();
if (type != typeof(string) && typeof(System.Collections.IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(type))
{
    var underlyingType = ((System.Collections.IEnumerable)paramValue).GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
}
```

And it has worked very well in all instances up until today when I passed in an `int[]` as I discovered to be an issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8145206/1693085).

So, what would the best way to get the underlying type of an `IEnumerable` that also accounts for value types be?

Thanks!!

Comment: So the desired result with an `int[]` is `int`?

Comment: Exactly, Tim - I feel I worded the question incorrectly - I'll edit it now

Comment: ",string ...Never a complex object or class" make no sense... Some edit would help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to know the type and if it's an `IEnumerable<T>`(!= `string`) you want the `T`? For arrays you can use [`Type.GetElementType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getelementtype(v=vs.71).aspx):

```
public static Type GetUnderlyingType(object paramValue)
{
    Type type = paramValue.GetType();
    var stringType = typeof(string);
    if (type == stringType)
        return stringType;
    else if (type.IsArray)
        type = type.GetElementType();
    else if (typeof(System.Collections.IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(type))
    {
        var genericArguments = ((System.Collections.IEnumerable) paramValue).GetType().GetGenericArguments();
        if(genericArguments.Length > 0)
            type = genericArguments[0];
    }
    return type;
}
```

Comment: This fails if you pass in a non-generic `IEnumerable` instance, or an `IEnumerable` instance where the first generic argument isn't the type of the items in a sequence, say, for a dictionary.

Comment: @JohnBustos Just because the method works for one or two test cases doesn't mean it actually works.  In fact, you'll find that a *significant* percentages of sequences won't actually work properly with this.  You can't  just test the code with `LIst<T>` and nothing else, and assume it works.

Comment: @Servy: you're right, so i have at least prevented the exception which was raised on accessing a non-available generic argument. On non generic enumerables the enumerable-type itself is returned. Or you know a way to get the contained object's type(it could change, for example in an ArrayList)?

Comment: Agreed, @Servy - It's just that for the purposes of what I'm using it in my class, the purpose is truly extremely simple - It just died on an int array which was a problem, but it will never be passed even an array of `object`

Comment: @JohnBustos If you know that the code is limited to a very small set of objects, then you should both *specify that in your question*, rather than asking about any arbitrary `IEnumerable`, and also *check for those specific types in your code*, so that the code can properly error (with a meaningful error message) when any other type is provided.

Answer (score 0):

As @Servy says, a non-generic `IEnumerable` sequence may contain elements of several different types.

If you only care about the first item in the sequence and assume that all other items are the same type, you could try something like this:

```
int[] paramValue = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
Type type = paramValue.GetType();
Type underlyingType;
if (type != typeof(string))
{
    System.Collections.IEnumerable e = paramValue as System.Collections.IEnumerable;
    if(e != null)
    {
        Type eType = e.GetType();
        if(eType.IsGenericType)
        {
            underlyingType = eType.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
        }
        else
        {
            foreach(var item in e)
            {
                underlyingType = item.GetType();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that, as an example, `underlyingType` will be `int` for the following `paramValue` though:

```
object[] paramValue = new object[] { 1, "a", "c" };
```

Comment: Not only can the first item not be of the same type as other items in the sequence, there might *be no items in the sequence*, iterating the sequence might be expensive or cause side effects, or it might not support being enumerated multiple times, thus preventing any actual [useful] use of the object later.  There are *lots* of ways for this to go wrong.

Comment: Certainly, but I guess it's the best you can do if you want to be able to get the type information of the items in the sequence.

Comment: I do apologize - I just worded the question terribly - What will be passed in will either be a scalar value or an `IEnumerable<T>` where T is of one of the simpler types such as string, double, int, bool, etc.

Answer (score -1):

An `IEnumerable` *doesn't have an underlying type*, at least, not other than `object`.  You know that each item in the sequence is an `object`, but you don't know any more than that.  If you want to work with sequences of items where all of those items are of the same type (where that type isn't `object` then you need to work with `IEnumerable<T>`, not `IEnumerable`.

As it is, any given `IEnumerable` given to you might have a string and an int and a custom object, all in the same sequence, so there *is* no common type there other than `object`.

Comment: Nothing you say is wrong, but your comment is only applicable when `paramValue` is of type `IEnumerable` (and not `IEnumerable<T>`). His check for the type of `IEnumerable` is a (flawed) approach at detecting an `IEnumerable<T>`, which is implicitly proven by the fact that he then immediately looks for the generic type `T`. Your answer, while technically correct, is addressing a case that is likely never encountered and not relevant for the question at hand.

Comment: @Flater But `IEnumerable` *has no generic type*.  As you say, trying to find it is flawed, because *it doesn't exist*.  Like I said in my answer, if the OP only wants to support objects implementing `IEnumerable<T>`, and not items implementing `IEnumerable`, then they need to check for `IEnumerable<T>`, not `IEnumerable`, else their code *can't* work.

Comment: I feel I simply worded the question incorrectly, I was goign to be passing in either a single value or an IEnumerable of Type T and needed to know what the T was... Thank you for your answer!

Comment: "else their code can't work" That is flatout wrong. It wouldn't be the **best** approach, but it would work. If the OP **never** supplies an `IEnumerable paramValue`, and only `IEnumerable<T>` or any non-`IEnumerable` type, then the issue you're commenting on **never** occurs (and the code will work without any compiler issues). Your issue only applies for cases where `paramValue` is of type `IEnumerable`, which contradicted by the premise of the question.

Comment: @JohnBustos If you want to require the object to be of `IEnumerable<T>` then *check for that*, as I said in my answer, rather than checking for `IEnumerable`.  Additionally, you cannot assume that the first generic argument of the type itself is the generic argument to `IEnumerable<T>`, even if that object implements `IEnumerable<T>`.  For example, the first generic argument of `Dictionary<int, string>` is `int`, but it implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int,string>>`, not `IEnumerable<int>`.

Comment: Servy, again you are raising issues that are not part of the question. Everything you say is correct but it has no bearing on the question at hand. The OP is not passing in dictionaries, nor is he passing non-generic IEnumerables. Your answer is a valid footnote, and an incentive to reevaluate the approach in general, but it is not an answer to the question that is asked here.

Comment: @Flater No, it's *not* the case that you can just pass in any object implementing `IEnumerable<T>` and the code will just work, because the generic argument of the object isn't necessarily the generic argument to the implementation of `IEnumerable<T>`.  The object may not even be generic, and thus *even if it implements `IEnumerable<T>`* the code can produce an incorrect answer, or error.

Comment: @Flater What's your basis for assuming that the OP isn't passing in dictionaries?  What's your basis for assuming they aren't passing in `IEnumerable` instances?  The answer *is* a valid answer to the question asked; it actually answers the question that was asked, rather than a question that you wish they would have asked, but didn't.  If the question said that they want to get the element type of a value where that value can *only* be an array, or a `List<T>`, and nothing else, then sure, other answers wouldn't be incorrect, but the question doesn't ask that.

Comment: @Servy: Straight from the horse's mouth: `I have used the following code to check if an object passed in is a single value or implements IEnumerable<T> (T being string, double, int, etc - Never a complex object or class)` This list is clearly exhaustive. All the fringe cases you list are valid logical holes, but if the OP never supplies these types then these issues will never be encountered. OP's mentions of exactly which types he is using renders your argument moot for his specific case (and again, I find your mention a valid footnote, just not an **answer** as it does not address `int[]`)

Comment: @Flater They edited that specific sentence *after I posted my answer*.  And saying "the list is exhaustive" when it contains "etc." in it is...a bit silly.  Also note that, even with that amended statement, the other answers are still wrong, as they still break any time the generic argument of the type isn't the same as the generic argument of the `IEnumerable<T>` it implements, which is rather often.  So you have *once again* assumed things not in the question.  The answer *does* answer the question.  The answer to the question that was asked, is that the type is *always* `object`.

Comment: `as they still break any time the generic argument of the type isn't the same as the generic argument of the IEnumerable<T>` So you agree that if the OP never supplies an argument of such a type, that the problem then doesn't arise?

Comment: @Flater Sure, but they have said no such thing, they've just said that they have arbitrary `IEnumerable` instances, and that assumption is *often* false for such instances.  Again, if the question specifically listed only a handful of specific types, which all met that criteria, then that would be different, but *they didn't ask that*.  In just the same way, if I'd written an answer that said "Just use `return int;` because you always have `int` sequences" that would be wrong, because the question has no such restriction.  Inventing restrictions that don't exist isn't acceptable.

Comment: Servy, I do appreciate your input and you are 100% correct, but it was my posting a badly-worded question. My situation is VERY limited and unique and @Flater was right in his comments. Again, you are correct in everything you say, but the accepted answer did fully answer my original question. Thanks so much to both of you!!!

Comment: @JohnBustos Again, if you have a very specific set of types that you're working with then *list out those types in your question*.  Flater's comments are strictly false.  They are entirely inaccurate in numerous ways, and are harmful for those that believe them to be the case, as it results in people using broken code without even realizing that it's broken.  The answer you were given *is very broken, and regularly crashes or gives the incorrect result*.  That you don't *realize* that it's broken *is a very big problem* and makes it much *worse* than if it just never worked at all.

Comment: @Servy `they've just said that they have arbitrary IEnumerable instances` That is just flatout wrong, and I've already quoted the OP explicitly contradicting that notion. `The answer you were given is very broken, and regularly crashes` I would agree with you if "broken" means "could potentially not work properly", but please show your justification for claiming that it crashes. I repeat again, it would only crash **if the OP actually supplies one of the types that cause it to crash**, which he doesn't, as per his own statements. The answer fits the range of types that the OP will use.

Comment: @Flater Again, they edited the question to ask a radically different question, after getting answers.  Additionally, even now the question just says that it can have arbitrary `IEnumerable<T>` instances, which is *still* enough to break Tims code a million different ways.  As for Tim's answer being broken, it returns the incorrect answer with *numerous* input values that are *valid input values* given the question asked.  It also will often crash if one of many possible *valid input values* is provided.  That makes it broken.

Comment: @Flater `The answer fits the range of types that the OP will use.` No, it *doesn't*. The question states that the range of types used is any `IEnumerable<T>` (where `T` is limited to certain types), and there are *many* types that meet those restriction that Tim's answer produces the incorrect answer for (which is even worse than it crashing, as it won't be immediately apparent that it didn't work properly).

Comment: `and there are many types that meet those restriction that Tim's answer produces the incorrect answer for` Name **one**. Observing the fact that the OP has explicitly stated that he only uses `IEnumerable<T>` with _T being string, double, int, etc - Never a complex object or class_ (as per the OP's question).

Comment: @Flater 1. Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.ValueCollection 2. SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>.KeyCollection (a few examples of .NET classes) 3. `class MyList:List<int>` 4. anything returned from an iterator block 5. The return value of many LINQ methods, like `OrderBy` or `Join`.  Is 5 examples enough for you?